# Synchronization through code chain

Tags: java, synchronization

Can someone please tell me if a Java thread executing the run command in "myClass" (in the following code) loses synchronization of an object between the time when the CustomList's get() command acquires it and the time when myClass's run requests the synchronization of the same object?

If the initial thread maintains the synchronization, then the central code of the "myThread" created by the CustomList's get command should never be able to fire until the original thread is finished with the requested Object.

```
public class myClass implements Runnable {

    private CustomList list;

    public myClass(){
        list = new CustomList();
        //Code to pack "list" goes here.
    }

    public void run(){
        int position = 0;
        while(position<list.size()){
            synchronized(list.get(position)){
                //Opperation's central code.
            }
            position++;
        }
    }

    public class CustomList extends ArrayList<Object> {

        public CustomList(){
            super();
        }

        public Object get(int i){
            Object o = super.get(i);
            synchronized(o){
                myThread thread = new myThread(o);
                thread.start();
                return o;
            }
        }

    }

    public class myThread extends Thread {

        private Object subject;

        public myThread(Object o){
            subject = o;
        }

        public void run(){
            synchronized(subject){
                //Do something to "subject"
                //BUT only AFTER the original Thread is finished with it.
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your end goal? Also, how much do you currently understand about `synchronized`?

Comment: Basically my end goal is to have an object that dispenses objects (much like a List or Map does) that's specifically designed to be used in a synchronized(Object) command. I want the dispenser device to register each such request for an Object with a second Thread, so that the second Thread will try to synchronized with that same Object, and then perform an operation on it, but *ONLY* when the initial Thread that requested the Object is finished with it. (i.e. has discarded it's synchronization with the Object).

Comment: My intent was to feed the Object to the second thread within the synchronized bracket of the CustomList's get function, just before the return line. Or, at least, at a comparable place within my own code.

But if the synchronization doesn't hold in my above example, as gkincker indicates, then it appears I'll have to find some other way of accomplishing this..

Comment: Even if the synchronization wasn't released after `get` returns, your current code is still the same as if you didn't have the synchronized block in `get`, which is why I'm totally clueless about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Forgive me, I was merely asking a simple question about whether synchronization gets passed along as I was hoping it did, I wasn't trying to go into deep detail about what my end goal was. I've edited my question, adding new code lines to try to illustrate in better detail what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. Your CustomList is not thread safe given the code you've presented.

To fix the problem, stop attempting custom synchronization. You don't understand it well enough yet. Instead, use `java.util.Collections.synchronizedList()` to wrap an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`.

```
private List<Object> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

Comment: Downvoted, because even with synchronizedList there might still be a race condition here, because we don't know what the asker is trying to do.

Comment: Aaand now I can't un-downvote since the asker clarified that they're only asking about this specific question and not about fixing their code. Good job StackOverflow. Sorry about that.

Comment: @immibis I made a trivial change to my answer so you can remove your downvote :)

Comment: Done. [15 characters]